# Python / Django Static files not load when debug is False

Tags: python, django, cpanel, litespeed

I have Django project and I deployed this project on Web Host. But I have a problem. Static files do not load when I set the debug variable in the settings file to False.

Host control panel: cPanel

Web Server: LiteSpeed

Comment: Can you share your settings.py content?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes. 140 static files added but it did not work.